# Can not to use httpclient to send httprequest in circulation?

Tags: java, http

I am try to make a tiny util so that I can send a HttpRequest repeatedly and I use HttpClient to do this.

But I have a problem, I can not send HttpRequest in circulation. To more detail, it can sent request at first cycle, but after that it can not send request and the thread is waiting at there.

there is the main code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    HttpResponse result = Launcher.bulider()
                .setCharSet("utf-8")  
                .setHttpMethod("GET") 
                .setUrl("http://www.baidu.com") 
                .fullResponse();

    System.out.println(result.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```

Launcher.java:

```
public abstract class Launcher {


 public static class bulider{

    private String httpMethod;

    private String url;

    private Map<String, String> params;

    private String charSet;

    private Class type;


    public bulider setHttpMethod(String httpMethod) {
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
        return this;
    }

    public bulider setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    public bulider setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
        return this;
    }

    public bulider setCharSet(String charSet) {
        this.charSet = charSet;
        return this;
    }


    public String data() {
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.GET)){
            return HttpTemplate.doGet(this.url,this.params,this.charSet);
        }
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST)){
            return HttpTemplate.doPost(this.url,this.params,this.charSet);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public <T> T jsonObject(Class<T> type) {
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.GET)) {
            return HttpTemplate.getReObj(type, this.url, this.params, this.charSet);
        }
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST)) {
            return HttpTemplate.postReObj(type, this.url, this.params, this.charSet);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public HttpResponse fullResponse() {
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.GET)) {
            return HttpTemplate.getReResponse(this.url, this.params, this.charSet);
        }
        if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST)) {
            return HttpTemplate.postReResponse(this.url, this.params, this.charSet);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public static bulider bulider(){
    return new bulider();
}
```

}

HttpTemplate.java:

```
public class HttpTemplate {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpTemplate.class);

private static final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
public static final String DEFAULT_CHARSET = "utf-8";

static {
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(6000).build();
    httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
}


public static String doGet(String url, Map<String, String> param, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = (HttpGet) initRequestParam("Get", url, param, charset);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (!String.valueOf(statusCode).startsWith("2")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Http Template Error :: status code " + statusCode);
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, charset);
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        return result;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String doPost(String url, Map<String, String> params, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = (HttpPost) initRequestParam("Post", url, params, charset);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (!String.valueOf(status).startsWith("2")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Http Template Error :: status error " + status);
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        return result;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}


public static <T> T getReObj(Class<T> type, String url, Map<String, String> param, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = (HttpGet) initRequestParam("Get", url, param, charset);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (!String.valueOf(statusCode).startsWith("2")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Http Template Error :: status code " + statusCode);
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, charset);
        }
        logger.info(result);
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        T resultNew = JSON.parseObject(result, type);
        logger.info(resultNew.getClass().toString());
        return resultNew;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public static <T> T postReObj(Class<T> type, String url, Map<String, String> params, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = (HttpPost) initRequestParam("Post", url, params, charset);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (!String.valueOf(status).startsWith("2")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Http Template Error :: status error " + status);
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, charset);
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        T resultNew = JSON.parseObject(result, type);
        return resultNew;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static HttpResponse getReResponse(String url, Map<String, String> param, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = (HttpGet) initRequestParam("Get", url, param, charset);
        return httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public static HttpResponse postReResponse(String url, Map<String, String> param, String charset) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = (HttpPost) initRequestParam("Post", url, param, charset);
        return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static HttpRequestBase initRequestParam(String methodName, String url, Map<String, String> params, String charset) {
    logger.info(url);
    if (!StringKit.isNotBlank(url)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == charset) {
        charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    }
    List<NameValuePair> pairList = null;
    if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
        pairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            String value = entry.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), value));
            }
        }
    }

    if ("Get".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
        try {

            if (pairList != null) {
                url += "?" + EntityUtils.toString(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairList, charset));
            }
            logger.info(url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            return httpGet;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if ("Post".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            if (pairList != null && !pairList.isEmpty()) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairList));
            }
            return httpPost;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

}

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>httpLaunch</groupId>
<artifactId>httpLaunch</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!--http client-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

there is the whole code:https://github.com/vzardlloo/http-launcher

Comment: The relevant code must be **in the question itself**.

Comment: I am worry the relevant code is too lang...i will add it to the question:-)

Comment: You need to consume the content of the response: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e145. Also, please respect the Java naming conventions, and fix your spelling: bulider, getReResponse, postReResponse, etc.

Comment: I know the mistake where i made,thx for your advice,i will fix them